# Форма обратной связи для каждого элемента списка bitrix

Tags: php, javascript, html, битрикс

работаю в битрикс с каталогом товаров.
Необходимо в списке товаров у каждого блока товара поставить ссылку "оставить заявку на обучение".
Форму я нашла она работает, но!!! присылается ни одно письмо по конкретному товару, а по всем товарам в данной категории.
Пример, вывода товара (код примерный):
[image: Пример блоков товаров]

```
<div class="bx_catalog_item_container" id="<? echo $strMainID; ?>"onclick="location.href='<? echo $arItem['DETAIL_PAGE_URL']; ?>';">
<div class="title_name"> echo $productTitle; ?>
</div>
<div class="item_price">echo $arItemIDs['PRICE']; ?>
</div>
<div class="item_articul1">echo echo $propID; ?>
</div>
<div class="bx-more2"> 
<a href="#inline" rel="nofollow" class="modalbox">Оставить заявку на товар</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".modalbox").fancybox();
    $("#f_contact").submit(function(){ return false; });
    $("#f_send").on("click", function(){

        // тут дальнейшие действия по обработке формы
        // закрываем окно, как правило делать это нужно после обработки данных
        $("#f_contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
            $(this).before("<p><strong>Ваше сообщение отправлено!</strong></p>");
            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div id="inline" style="display:none;">
 <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/form/form_dpo.php");?>
</div>
</div>
```

Возможно есть рекомендации идеи по такой форме, где косяк? И кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей?
Я так чувствую, что дело то за малым остается, возможно в самом шаблоне битрикса элемента может надо подкрутить или в форме обратной связи?

Код формы обратной связи:

```
<body>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name']; if ($name == '') {unset($name);}}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email']; if ($email == '') {unset($email);}}
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {$sub = $_POST['sub']; if ($sub == '') {unset($sub);}}
if (isset($_POST['body'])) {$body = $_POST['body']; if ($body == '') {unset($body);}}

if (isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($sub) && isset($body)){

$address = "balabanovaei@miep.ru";
$mes = "Имя: $name \nE-mail: $email \nТема: $sub \nТекст: $body \nПрограмма: $productTitle";
$send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email");
if ($send == 'true')
{echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно. Перейдите на главную страницу блога <a href=''>Главная страница</a>,и вы сможете продолжить ваш просмотр";}
else {echo "Ошибка, сообщение не отправлено!";}

}
else
{
echo "Заполнили все поля!!!";
}
?>

<h2>Форма обратной связи.</h2>

<form name="MyForm" action="" method="post">
<p><input class="input" name="name" type="text" style="width:15%" /> Ваше имя*</p>
<p><input class="input" name="email" type="text" style="width:15%" /> Электронная почта*</p>
<p><input class="input" name="sub" type="text" style="width:15%" /> Тема сообщения</p>
<p>Текст сообщения:<br /><textarea name="body" cols="1" rows="5" style="width:30%" /></textarea></p>
<p><input id="submit" value="Отправить" type="submit" /></p>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. создайте почтовое событие
2. создайте почтовый шаблон
3. в ссылке открытия попап допишите доп атрибут где передаете ID (если будете передавать ID то, в файле обработчика вам нужно делать запрос через ciblock element getlist и вытаскивать название элемента) или название элемента.
4. в вызове fancybox допишите функцию на событие перед открытием, получите ID или NAME элемента и передайте ее на поле input формы.
5. на форму повесьте ajax обработчик по отправке данных.
6. напишите свой php обработчик по данным

и усе...

Answer (score 1):

Расширю ответ автора выше:
Вытащите ID элемента на клиент, затем формой передавайте на сервер обработчику.
  с помощью ciblock element getlist собираете необходимые данные в массив

```
$arFields= array(
            "ID" => ''
            "NAME" => '',
            // всякие данные
        );
```

скармливаете почтовому шаблону
        CEvent::Send("ВАШ_ШАБЛОН", "s1", $arFields, "N");

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сейчас пробую!

Comment: Не понимаю как передать id... все попытки тщетны.

Comment: Помещаете в скрытый инпут <input id="" type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$arOb["ID"]?>">

Comment: и принимаете $Id = $_POST['id'];

Comment: Я поняла что Вы имеете в виду, но смотрите, у меня не из формы идут данные. А из блока товара я запускаю ссылку на форму с помощью href="#inline", соответственно в форму не попадают данные товара. А как передать наименование товара в форму я хз, как только не пыталась, в форму попадает пустой id

Comment: Я так понял что форма открывается в popup по клику на href="#inline", если да, то: в блок товара вытаскиваете ID из php (скрываете если нужно). далее по клику на href="#inline" вешаете событие JS кот. вписывает ID в форму. Если используете fancybox можно сюда прописать afterShow: function () {}